# Ubuntu Touch and device compatibilities

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-for-android

What tablet android devices are even supported? I have a Pantech Element (P4100)

Answer (score 0):

Yours isn't supported, only some Nexus devices are actively supported
(full list here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)